# Sequelize hasMany association returns only a single object

Tags: sequelize.js, feathers-sequelize

The `hasMany` association should return a list of object, rights? I have a `user` record and a few `connections` records connected to it.

model `connections`:

```
userId: {
      field: 'user_id',
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
```

model `users`:

```
(users as any).associate = function associate(models: any) {
    models.users.hasMany(models.connections, {
      as: 'connections',
      foreignKey: 'user_id'
    });
  };
```

I include the `connections` model by adding it to the sequelize query params:

```
include: [{ model: context.app.service('connections').Model, as: 'connections' }],
```

The end result is that the `connections` property in the `user` response is a single object instead of an array of objects.
I logged the Sequelize’s query executions and tried directly in the DB the raw query that Sequelize does for this particular call and it returns a list of records, as it should. But when I query it through the API, it returns just a single object instead of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the query from Sequelize needs to be marked as `raw`.
So, in the `sequelize` object, you gotta include the `raw: true` param. This will, unfortunately, result in returning a Sequelize native object (the one that has the `defaultValues` prop). You can get it serialized into a normal JavaScript object by calling `.get()` on the result from Sequelize.

So, to sum up, you gotta add `raw: true` on the same level as the `include` prop, like so:

```
{
  include: [{ model: ...],
  raw: true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
.findAll({
   raw : false // <===
})
```

Documentation: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html

```
// Only Set this to true if you don't have a model definition for your query.
raw: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in included table:- Child table

separate: true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).